# what is appId in electronjs

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I am new in electronjs application development. And I am using **electron-builder** for distribution.

But I can't figure out what is the use of this `appId` property in package.json

```
{
  "build": {
    "appId": "your.id",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms, appId is a name that the client's computer is using to identify. This is particularly useful and you must've noticed it when you are trying to launch an app thar's already open, your OS would open the minimised version, rather than opening a new instance of the same app.